# What can replace vegetable butter?

Tags: substitutions, cake, butter

I am making a dairy- and gluten-free cake. What can I use to replace vegetable butter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Butter substitute for baking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6227/butter-substitute-for-baking) - althought I'm not absolutely sure what "vegetable butter" is supposed to be.

Comment: Indeed, are you talking about something like pumpkin or apple butter, or are you talking about margarine?

Comment: If by "vegetable butter" you mean a butter substitute made from vegetable oil, it probably already is dairy- and gluten-free.

Comment: Vegetable butter is vegetable fat with the consistency of butter - e.g. cocoa butter or maybe coconut oil. I've personally never seen this used in cake, but if it is part of the recipe (or if the question is about vegetable *shortening*) then it is indeed already dairy- and gluten-free. The only replacement would be... *butter*.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the kosher symbol on different types of butter.  You will need to find a substitute with the word "Parve" on it.  Parve means no dairy products.  From there just check the labels to make sure it is gluten free.  Other things that I have used to replace butter have been olive oil or applesauce (works great in brownies).

Here is a chart if you would like to substitute olive oil for the butter.  http://www.amazingoliveoil.com/substitute-olive-oil-for-butter.html

Comment: Actually, *parve* means neither meat nor milk. Such items can be then used in kosher kitchen with either meat or milk products without problem. I doubt whether one would be allowed to sell *parve butter* as butter is by definition a milk product, and parve means that it's not a milk product.

Comment: Well, as I have Jewish friends that use parve products for their butter replacement. So, I do believe that it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

We usually bake with [Earth Balance Buttery Sticks](http://www.earthbalancenatural.com/eb_pdfs/products/vegan-sticks-nutrition-info.pdf) in any recipe that calls for butter. They are dairy and gluten free and can be easily measured by cutting according to the scale on the side of the wrapper, just like regular dairy butter.

If a liquid product is needed, Earth Balance can be melted and will provide more flavor than simply using oil.

Comment: Your link shows that the ingredients are different vegetable oils. Your description (sticks, wrapper) suggests they have butter consistency. Which means that they are "vegetable butter" - the exact thing the OP is trying to replace. (At least by Aaronut's definition, and I accept that as correct, because it makes most sense of all alternatives I can think of).

Comment: @rumtscho - Vegetable oils and butter consistency, true. My read on Aaronut's definition was for single ingredient vegetable butters, (I may have fixated on that because he specifically mentioned cocoa butter) and my read on the OP's question was that she was likely looking for an alternative to a more traditional margarine product, which will often still contain dairy. Of course, we're all just shooting in the dark unless the OP clarifies her question for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use oil in cake. I wouldn't use olive oil for a sweet cake. Try any neutral tasting oil or if you are rich, there is stuff like pistache oil wich will undoubtedly give a fancy cake.

Comment: Actually, you can make quite a tasty sweet cake with olive oil. I wouldn't use it for a chocolate cake, but I've made an Italian cake called Torta di Mandorle, which is an almond-and-olive-oil cake that is very good.

Comment: I always use olive oil in my cakes, even chocolate.  I think it makes them come out moister and fluffier.